# Does R2 have a color holoprojector?

Tags: star-wars, r2-d2

Why is the holoproject of Luke in color during the Jabba the Hutt scene in *Return of the Jedi*?  To my knowledge, all of the other holoprojectors are blue.

[image: holoprojection]

Comment: I disagree @Valorum, I'm not seeing a dupe there.

Comment: Oh unless it being set canonically later means the tech improved?

Comment: @Edlothiad - It speaks to a fundamental misunderstanding of holotechnology in Star Wars. Note that there are colour holo-projectors in films set in earlier timeframes

Comment: I'm confused why NKCampbell's dup comment has more upvotes than Valorum's...

Comment: @ArthurDent When you vote to close a post as "Duplicate", it will auto-generate a comment. When more people vote to close the post with the same duplicate target, it will auto-upvote the generated comment. Here, Valorum (probably) manually posted the comment using that format because he wanted to link directly to the answer; while NKCampbell generated it through the tool. Thus, attributing to the generated comment when more people vote. It's been a while since I've used SE regularly, so I could be off. It could be that he pasted a different link in the tool, creating a different comment.

Comment: @Thebluefish Wow I never knew that, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, everyone!  I didn't realize there were color projects in the Rebel series and I forgot about the colorized Death Star projection.

Comment: Still, R2 seems to have been upgraded from episode 4.  Is there an explanation of this somewhere in the Star Wars lore?

Comment: @DonBurdette Colour TVs can still display black & white programs, if required.  Perhaps R2's projector has always been capable of colourized projection, but Leia simply recorded her message to Obi-Wan in monochrome.  (It was dark in the passage where she was recording it, so maybe R2 calculated that monochrome was better since it would just be a dark blur in colour, or perhaps Leia hit the wrong button when beginning the message - she WAS in a hurry what with the Tantive IV being boarded and all.)

Comment: @Arthurdent - As a gold tag badge holder in this category, my dupe close vote is binding. I posted a comment to indicate to other readers that this might be a dupe. I wasn't 100% confident so I didn't vote.